# Railway oriented programming with Async operations

Tags: asynchronous, error-handling, f#, function-composition

Previously asked similar question but somehow I'm not finding my way out, attempting again with another example.

The code as a starting point (a bit trimmed) is available at https://ideone.com/zkQcIU.

(it has some issue recognizing `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Result` type, not sure why)

Essentially all operations have to be pipelined with the previous function feeding the result to the next one. The operations have to be async and they should return error to the caller in case an exception occurred.

The requirement is to give the caller either result or fault. All functions return a Tuple populated with either **Success** `type Article` or **Failure** with `type Error` object having descriptive `code` and `message` returned from the server.

Will appreciate a working example around my code both for the callee and the caller in an answer.

**Callee Code**

```
type Article = {
    name: string
}

type Error = {
    code: string
    message: string
}

let create (article: Article) : Result<Article, Error> =  
    let request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
    request.Method <- "GET"
    try
        use response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd())) 
        Ok ((new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Article>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Article)
    with
        | :? WebException as e ->  
        use reader = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream())
        use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd())) 
        Error ((new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Error>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Error)
```

**Rest of the chained methods** - Same signature and similar bodies. You can actually reuse the body of `create` for `update`, `upload`, and `publish` to be able to test and compile code.

```
let update (article: Article) : Result<Article, Error>
    // body (same as create, method <- PUT)

let upload (article: Article) : Result<Article, Error>
    // body (same as create, method <- PUT)

let publish (article: Article) : Result<Article, Error>
    // body (same as create, method < POST)
```

**Caller Code**

```
let chain = create >> Result.bind update >> Result.bind upload >> Result.bind publish
match chain(schemaObject) with 
    | Ok article -> Debug.WriteLine(article.name)
    | Error error -> Debug.WriteLine(error.code + ":" + error.message)
```

**Edit**

Based on the answer and matching it with Scott's implementation (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIxpD.png), to help in comparison and in better understanding.

```
let bind2 (switchFunction : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>) = 
    fun (asyncTwoTrackInput : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>) -> async {
        let! twoTrackInput = asyncTwoTrackInput
        match twoTrackInput with
        | Ok s -> return! switchFunction s
        | Error err -> return Error err
    }
```

**Edit 2** Based on F# implementation of bind

```
let bind3 (binder : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>) (asyncResult : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>) = async {
    let! result = asyncResult
    match result with
    | Error e -> return Error e
    | Ok x -> return! binder x
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [Suave source code](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/4e7ff951f1a85daaceea1a2dcf5408983ea2c200/src/Suave/WebPart.fs), and specifically the `WebPart.bind` function. In Suave, a WebPart is a function that takes a context (a "context" is the current request and the response so far) and returns a result of type `Async<context option>`. The semantics of chaining these together are that if the async returns `None`, the next step is skipped; if it returns `Some value`, the next step is called with `value` as the input. This is pretty much the same semantics as the `Result` type, so you could almost copy the Suave code and adjust it for Result instead of Option. E.g., something like this:

```
module AsyncResult

let bind (f : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>) (a : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>)  : Async<Result<'b, 'c>> = async {
    let! r = a
    match r with
    | Ok value ->
        let next : Async<Result<'b, 'c>> = f value
        return! next
    | Error err -> return (Error err)
}

let compose (f : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'e>>) (g : 'b -> Async<Result<'c, 'e>>) : 'a -> Async<Result<'c, 'e>> =
    fun x -> bind g (f x)

let (>>=) a f = bind f a
let (>=>) f g = compose f g
```

Now you can write your chain as follows:

```
let chain = create >=> update >=> upload >=> publish
let result = chain(schemaObject) |> Async.RunSynchronously
match result with 
| Ok article -> Debug.WriteLine(article.name)
| Error error -> Debug.WriteLine(error.code + ":" + error.message)
```

Caution: I haven't been able to verify this code by running it in F# Interactive, since I don't have any examples of your create/update/etc. functions. It should work, in principle — the types all fit together like Lego building blocks, which is how you can tell that F# code is probably correct — but if I've made a typo that the compiler would have caught, I don't yet know about it. Let me know if that works for you.

**Update:** In a comment, you asked whether you need to have both the `>>=` and `>=>` operators defined, and mentioned that you didn't see them used in the `chain` code. I defined both because they serve different purposes, just like the `|>` and `>>` operators serve different purposes. `>>=` is like `|>`: it passes a *value* into a *function*. While `>=>` is like `>>`: it takes *two functions* and combines them. If you would write the following in a non-AsyncResult context:

```
let chain = step1 >> step2 >> step3
```

Then that translates to:

```
let asyncResultChain = step1AR >=> step2AR >=> step3AR
```

Where I'm using the "AR" suffix to indicate versions of those functions that return an `Async<Result<whatever>>` type. On the other hand, if you had written that in a pass-the-data-through-the-pipeline style:

```
let result = input |> step1 |> step2 |> step3
```

Then that would translate to:

```
let asyncResult = input >>= step1AR >>= step2AR >>= step3AR
```

So that's why you need both the `bind` and `compose` functions, and the operators that correspond to them: so that you can have the equivalent of either the `|>` or the `>>` operators for your AsyncResult values.

BTW, the operator "names" that I picked (`>>=` and `>=>`), I did not pick randomly. These are the standard operators that are used all over the place for the "bind" and "compose" operations on values like Async, or Result, or AsyncResult. So if you're defining your own, stick with the "standard" operator names and other people reading your code won't be confused.

**Update 2**: Here's how to read those type signatures:

```
'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>
```

This is a function that takes type A, and returns an `Async` wrapped around a `Result`. The `Result` has type B as its success case, and type C as its failure case.

```
Async<Result<'a, 'c>>
```

This is a value, not a function. It's an `Async` wrapped around a `Result` where type A is the success case, and type C is the failure case.

So the `bind` function takes two parameters:

- a function from A to an async of (either B or C)).
- a value that's an async of (either A or C)).

And it returns:

- a value that's an async of (either B or C).

Looking at those type signatures, you can already start to get an idea of what the `bind` function will do. It will take that value that's either A or C, and "unwrap" it. If it's C, it will produce an "either B or C" value that's C (and the function won't need to be called). If it's A, then in order to convert it to an "either B or C" value, it will call the `f` function (which takes an A).

All this happens within an async context, which adds an extra layer of complexity to the types. It might be easier to grasp all this if you look at the [basic version of `Result.bind`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/e19ddca7d6049ae04cc6a827e803555285d19b26/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/result.fs), with no async involved:

```
let bind (f : 'a -> Result<'b, 'c>) (a : Result<'a, 'c>) =
    match a with
    | Ok val -> f val
    | Error err -> Error err
```

In this snippet, the type of `val` is `'a`, and the type of `err` is `'c`.

**Final update**: There was one comment from the chat session that I thought was worth preserving in the answer (since people almost never follow chat links). Developer11 asked,

> ... if I were to ask you what `Result.bind` in my example code maps to your approach, can we rewrite it as `create >> AsyncResult.bind update`? It worked though. Just wondering i liked the short form and as you said they have a standard meaning? (in haskell community?)

My reply was:

> Yes. If the `>=>` operator is properly written, then `f >=> g` will **always** be equivalent to `f >> bind g`. In fact, that's precisely the definition of the `compose` function, though that might not be immediately obvious to you because `compose` is written as `fun x -> bind g (f x)` rather than as `f >> bind g`. But those two ways of writing the compose function would be *exactly equivalent*. It would probably be very instructive for you to sit down with a piece of paper and draw out the function "shapes" (inputs & outputs) of both ways of writing compose.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167495/discussion-on-answer-by-rmunn-railway-oriented-programming-with-async-operations).

Comment: P.S. For anyone else who finds this later, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697022/why-isnt-f-able-to-resolve-overload-between-async-and-asyncresult has another good implementation of AsyncResult (in Gustavo's answer)

Comment: @rmunn is there a problem if my async fun changes it's signature to a built-in type instead of custom type, now it's `Async<Result<string, Error>>`, before it was `Async<Result<Article, Error>>`

Comment: please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586488/type-mismatch-error-for-async-chained-operations

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to use Railway Oriented Programming here? If you just want to run a sequence of operations and return information about the first exception that occurs, then F# already provides a language support for this using exceptions. You do not need Railway Oriented Programming for this. Just define your `Error` as an exception:

```
exception Error of code:string * message:string
```

Modify the code to throw the exception (also note that your `create` function takes `article` but does not use it, so I deleted that):

```
let create () = async {  
    let ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Error>)
    let request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com") :?> HttpWebRequest
    request.Method <- "GET"
    try
        use response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
        use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd())) 
        return ds.ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Article
    with
        | :? WebException as e ->  
        use reader = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream())
        use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd())) 
        return raise (Error (ds.ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Error)) }
```

And then you can compose functions just by sequencing them in `async` block using `let!` and add exception handling:

```
let main () = async {
  try
    let! created = create ()
    let! updated = update created
    let! uploaded = upload updated
    Debug.WriteLine(uploaded.name)
  with Error(code, message) ->
    Debug.WriteLine(code + ":" + message) }
```

If you wanted more sophisticated exception handling, then Railway Oriented Programming might be useful and there is certainly a way of integrating it with `async`, but if you just want to do what you described in your question, then you can do that much more easily with just standard F#.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I appreciate your answer, to answer your question `Why do you want to use Railway Oriented Programming here` because I want to have a fluent functional interface, it becomes imperative programming when i take  result from `create` and feed into `update` manually and continue the same with the rest of the chain.

Comment: now let me ask you something different, do I even need these functions to be asynchronous or I continue to have them in synchronous way just the way they are right now?

Comment: @Developer11 There is nothing imperative about passing values around using `let`. A legitimate reason for using ROP is that you need different way of composing errors (say, collect all rather than just the first one), but if that's not the case, you are just making your code unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: You need the functions to be asynchronous if you want to avoid blocking system threads. That depends on what you are actually doing :)

Comment: `say, collect all rather than just the first one`, not sure what you mean? but the chain can't collect all errors, as soon any method in the chain throws an error the chain will break and the caller will get the error.

Comment: @Developer11 Exactly, that's why you should use exceptions :-). ROP is nice for problems like input validation where you can continue even if there is an error - then you can collect multiple errors and report them all, rather than one by one. But in this case, exceptions are encoding the logic you need.

Comment: in ROP, I could do both, either break the chain or continue collecting all the errors, and I'm also getting the picture of your idea, my inclination towards ROP is because of method chaining/piping `>>=` and if I'm not wrong it's not possible because of `async` and `let!` in this answer, we are forced to retrieve the result first and then feed it to the next function in another call

Comment: `if you want to avoid blocking system threads` let's say I've this deployed as a web service and if I'm not using async essentially means that if userA's request is in progress, userB has to wait for userA to finish?

Comment: @Developer11 This is beyond the scope of what we can reasonably answer in SO comments. I really recommend reading some longer introduction to asynchronous workflows in one of the F# books - it should answer these questions much better than a comment would.

Comment: @Developer11 Chapter 13 of https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-functional-programming is one source, but most other F# books will cover asyncs.