# type mismatch error for async chained operations

Tags: f#

Previously had a very compact and comprehensive answer for my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399474/railway-oriented-programming-with-async-operations).

I had it working for my custom type but now due to some reason I had to change it to string type which is now causing type mismatch errors.

```
module AsyncResult =
    let bind (binder : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>) (asyncFun : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>) : Async<Result<'b, 'c>> =
        async {
            let! result = asyncFun
            match result with
            | Error e -> return Error e
            | Ok x -> return! binder x
        }

    let compose (f : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'e>>) (g : 'b -> Async<Result<'c, 'e>>) = fun x -> bind g (f x)
    let (>>=) a f = bind f a
    let (>=>) f g = compose f g
```

**Railway Oriented functions**

```
let create (json: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
    let url = "http://api.example.com"
    let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Uri url)
    request.Method <- "GET"

     async {
         try
             // http call
             return Ok "result"
         with :? WebException as e -> 
             return Error {Code = 500; Message = "Internal Server Error"}
     }
```

**test**

type mismatch error for the `AsyncResult.bind` line

```
let chain = create
         >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))


match chain "initial data" |> Async.RunSynchronously with
 | Ok data -> Assert.IsTrue(true)
 | Error error -> Assert.IsTrue(false)
```

**Error details**:

> EntityTests.fs(101, 25): [FS0001] Type mismatch. Expecting a   `'(string -> string -> Async<Result<string,Error>>) -> 'a'`   but given a   `'Async<Result<'b,'c>> -> Async<Result<'d,'c>>'`   The type `'string -> string -> Async<Result<string,Error>>'` does not match the type `'Async<Result<'a,'b>>'`.
>
> EntityTests.fs(101, 25): [FS0001] Type mismatch. Expecting a   `'(string -> string -> Async<Result<string,Error>>) -> 'a'`   but given a   `'Async<Result<string,'b>> -> Async<Result<string,'b>>'`   The type `'string -> string -> Async<Result<string,Error>>'` does not match the type `'Async<Result<string,'a>>'`.

**Edit**

**Curried or partial application**

In context of above example, is it the problem with curried functions? for instance if create function has this signature.

```
let create (token: string) (json: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
```

and then later build chain with curried function

```
let chain = create "token" >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))
```

---

**Edit 2**
Is there a problem with following case?

signature

```
let create (token: Token) (entityName: string) (entityType: string) (publicationId: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
```

test

```
let chain = create token >> AsyncResult.bind ( fun (result: string) -> async {return Ok "more results"} )

match chain "test" "article" "pubid" |> Async.RunSynchronously with
```

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of error messages; they're useless to anyone doing a text search who might need to find this question later. Copy and paste them in text form. I've done it for you this time so that you can see how your error messages *should* be pasted. If you click on "edit" to see the Markdown source, you'll notice I prefixed the messages with a single `>` character: that's how you do a blockquote (one `>` per paragraph or per line; use the preview window to be sure your formatting is correct). I also added backticks around the types so that they would be fixed-font.

Comment: Thanks. I'll note that. As you can see there was an attempt, I might have a bit of indentation issue in my question but I double checked everything in my code, I've visual clues of tabs and spaces and see everything aligned, i suspect problem is somewhere else. please advise.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a different `create` function in scope in your test code. To verify that, try to rename the `create` function to something different and see if the error persists.

Comment: I've looked through your edit and I don't see any obvious type errors (the most common newbie mistake is forgetting to pass one parameter, which means instead of a value you end up with a function because of currying, and if you're a newbie you then get confused for a while). I suspect that Fyodor Soikin is right and you may have some other `create` function. If you're using VS Code, try putting your cursor on the word `create` in `let chain = create >> (...)` and hitting F12 for "go to definition". If you're in Rider, try a Ctrl+click for "go to definition". Make sure it's the right function.

Comment: It's weird, it points to the right function. I created an isolated project with a single function and a test, I guess there's something else. i'm sharing my screen for a quick look if you will, https://zoom.us/j/272821510

Comment: see edit2 please, if there's a problem this? I'm considering if there's an issue with passing parameters.

Comment: @Developer11 - See my update. Your edit 2 was the key detail that we needed to know to answer your *actual problem*, which is that your `chain` function takes more than one data parameter. P.S. I have to leave now and I'll be away from Stack Overflow for not quite 24 hours but close. Don't expect any more answers or comments from me for a long while.

Comment: Thanks @rmunn. I'll wait. meanwhile I'll change this function based on one input by composing fields into a record. It seems to me that I shouldn't have done it if I'm working with ROP or Monads (it derived from the word mono i guess), please also advise in that sense.

Comment: I'll read about apply and perhaps will help to understand elevated world, and I look forward to your solution about apply since I'll need it going forward, for example `(upload "thumbnail.jpg")`, here I'm pre-binding or applying a parameter before placing it in the chain

Comment: I have a couple minutes right now, so I'll just say that I was wrong about needing apply in this situation. You just need to supply enough parameters to `create`. E.g., `let chain token entityName entityType = create token entityName entityType >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result : string) -> ...`. Then the types will line up because you're passing a `string -> Async<Result<whatever>>` function into `bind`.

Comment: you mean `let chain = create token "test" "article" >> AsyncResult.bind ( fun (result: string) -> async {return Ok "more results"} )`??, you said `let chain` with params?

Comment: I was thrown off by errors in `AsyncResult.bind` part not giving me enough clues, like @Snapshot says phantom errors.

Comment: `let chain token entityName entityType =` this is new for me, declaration + partial application together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** At the front of the answer, even, since **your edit 2 changes everything**.

In your edit 2, you have finally revealed your *actual* code, and your problem is very simple: you're misunderstanding how the types work in a curried F# function.

When your `create` function looked like `let create (json: string) = ...`, it was a function of one parameter. It took a string, and returned a result type (in this case, `Async<Result<string, Error>>`). So the function signature was `string -> Async<Result<string, Error>>`.

But the `create` function you've just shown us is a different type entirely. It takes *four* parameters (one `Token` and three strings), not one. That means its signature is:

```
Token -> string -> string -> string -> Async<Result<string, Error>>
```

Remember how [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/) works: any function of multiple parameters can be thought of as a series of functions of one parameter, which return the "next" function in that chain. E.g., `let add3 a b c = a + b + c` is of type `int -> int -> int -> int`; this means that `add3 1` returns a function that's equivalent to `let add2 b c = 1 + b + c`. And so on.

Now, keeping currying in mind, look at your function type. When you pass a single Token value to it as you do in your example (where it's called as `create token`, you get a function of type:

```
string -> string -> string -> Async<Result<string, Error>>
```

This is a function that takes a string, which returns *another function* that takes a string, which returns *a **third** function* which takes a string and returns an `Async<Result<whatever>>`. Now compare that to the type of the `binder` parameter in your `bind` function:

```
(binder : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>)
```

Here, `'a` is `string`, so is `'b`, and `'c` is `Error`. So when the generic `bind` function is applied to your specific case, it's looking for a function of type `string -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>`. But you're giving it a function of type `string -> string -> string -> Async<Result<string, Error>>`. Those two function types are **not the same**!

That's the fundamental cause of your type error. You're trying to apply a *function that returns a function that returns function that returns a result of type X* to a design pattern (the `bind` design pattern) that expects a *function that returns a result of type X*. What you need is the design pattern called `apply`. I have to leave quite soon so I don't have time to write you an explanation of how to use `apply`, but fortunately [Scott Wlaschin has already written a good one](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/). It covers a lot, not just "apply", but you'll find the details about `apply` in there as well. And that's the cause of your problem: you used `bind` when you needed to use `apply`.

**Original answer follows:**

I don't yet know for a fact what's causing your problem, but I have a suspicion. But first, I want to comment that the parameter names for your `AsyncResult.bind` are wrong. Here's what you wrote:

```
    let bind (binder : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>)
             (asyncFun : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>) : Async<Result<'b, 'c>> =
```

(I moved the second parameter in line with the first parameter so it wouldn't scroll on Stack Overflow's smallish column size, but that would compile correctly if the types were right: since the two parameters are lined up vertically, F# would know that they are both belonging to the same "parent", in this case a function.)

Look at your second parameter. You've named it `asyncFun`, but there's no arrow in its type description. That's not a function, it's a value. A function would look like `something -> somethingElse`. You should name it something like `asyncValue`, not `asyncFun`. By naming it `asyncFun`, you're setting yourself up for confusion later.

Now for the answer to the question you asked. I think your problem is this line, where you've fallen afoul of the [F# "offside rule"](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/):

```
let chain = create
         >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))
```

Note the position of the `>>` operator, which is **to the left of its first operand**. Yes, the F# syntax appears to allow that in most situations, but I suspect that if you simply change that function definition to the following, your code will work:

```
let chain =
    create
 >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))
```

Or, better yet because [it's good style to make the `|>` (and `>>`) operators line up with their first operand](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md#pipeline-operators):

```
let chain =
    create
    >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))
```

If you look carefully at the rules that Scott Wlaschin lays out in https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-syntax/, you'll note that his examples where he shows exceptions to the "offside rule", he writes them like this:

```
let f g h =   g   // defines a new line at col 15
           >> h   // ">>" allowed to be outside the line
```

Note how the `>>` character is **still to the right** of the `=` in the function definition. I don't know exactly what the F# spec says about the combination of function definitions and the offside rule (Scott Wlaschin is great, but he's not the spec so he could be wrong, and I don't have time to look up the spec right now), but I've seen it do funny things that I didn't quite expect when I wrote functions with part of the function definition on the same line as the function, and the rest on the next line.

E.g., I once wrote something like this, which didn't work:

```
let f a = if a = 0 then
        printfn "Zero"
    else
        printfn "Non-zero"
```

But then I changed it to this, which did work:

```
let f a =
    if a = 0 then
        printfn "Zero"
    else
        printfn "Non-zero"
```

I notice that in Snapshot's answer, he made your `chain` function be defined on a single line, and that worked for him. So I suspect that that's your problem.

**Rule of thumb:** If your function has anything after the `=` on the same line, make the function all on one line. If your function is going to be two lines, put nothing after the `=`. E.g.:

```
let f a b = a + b  // This is fine
let g c d =
    c * d  // This is also fine
let h x y = x
          + y  // This is asking for trouble
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm working on a totally isolated project with actors from the question only to narrow down the issue, secondly I do have my own type `Error (code, message)`, i hope this isn't in conflict with `Error of match statement`

Comment: please have a look at my edit, I noticed it's the problem with curried or partial application functions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that the error stems from a minor change in indentation since adding a single space to an FSharp program changes its meaning, the FSharp compiler than quickly reports phantom errors because it interprets the input differently. I just pasted it in and added bogus classes and removed some spaces and now it is working just fine.

```
module AsyncResult =

    [<StructuralEquality; StructuralComparison>]
    type Result<'T,'TError> = 
    | Ok of ResultValue:'T
    | Error of ErrorValue:'TError

    let bind (binder : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'c>>) (asyncFun : Async<Result<'a, 'c>>) : Async<Result<'b, 'c>> =
        async {
            let! result = asyncFun
            match result with
            | Error e -> return Error e
            | Ok x -> return! binder x
        }

    let compose (f : 'a -> Async<Result<'b, 'e>>) (g : 'b -> Async<Result<'c, 'e>>) = fun x -> bind g (f x)
    let (>>=) a f = bind f a
    let (>=>) f g = compose f g

open AsyncResult
open System.Net

type Assert =
    static member IsTrue (conditional:bool) = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(conditional)


type Error = {Code:int; Message:string}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let create (json: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
        let url = "http://api.example.com"
        let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Uri url)
        request.Method <- "GET"

        async {
             try
                 // http call
                 return Ok "result"
             with :? WebException as e -> 
                 return Error {Code = 500; Message = "Internal Server Error"}
        }

    let chain = create >> AsyncResult.bind (fun (result: string) -> (async {return Ok "more results"}))

    match chain "initial data" |> Async.RunSynchronously with
    | Ok data -> Assert.IsTrue(true)
    | Error error -> Assert.IsTrue(false)

    0
```

Comment: As a side note I recommend enabling visible spaces in your editor of choice if this is supported so that spaces are shown as dots which is far easier to spot than a difference in spaces.

Comment: double checked everything, couldn't find. any hint for probable indenting issue, like where

Comment: I can confirm that your solution is working but I'm still trying to locate error in my code. I moved the chain in one line, so no indentation issue there, if i replace it with some assert line it works though

Comment: can you please get on a zoom meeting with me?

Comment: async { in let create is indented one space too far.

Comment: I've been fixing the indentation manually in the question, and I think i still have the problem, can you please join https://zoom.us/j/823632854 I can share my screen

Comment: I am afraid I have to decline you offer, I have to learn for my finals. That being said if I had to make a guess I would say that you already have a function (or type) defined as "Error" and that it conflicts with your own type called error. Have you tried to rename the type?

Comment: I did rename but still no success,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167934/discussion-between-snapshot-and-developer11).